# NoReverseMatch for submitting my form on my profile page

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a blog project for a assignment and i have all functionality except for my user profiles editing and deleting.

I have created the profile page and ability to edit the page. When i then submit my update request, i can see that it submits the change as after i get the error the profile page is updated.

I am getting this error and i know it is due to the redirect but i cannot figure out for the life of me how to just redirect back to the user profile. I have tried to just use a httpredirect or reverse and now using reverse_lazy as that has worked fine for blog posts and comments and edits.

This is my error and code bellow.
I belive it is down to the get_success_url and am hoping that someone has had this error or knows the best fix for this. Thank you

> NoReverseMatch at /1/edit_profile_page/
> Reverse for 'show_profile_page' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P[0-9]+)/profile/\Z']

Views.py

```
class EditProfile(LoginRequiredMixin,
                  SuccessMessageMixin,
                  UserPassesTestMixin,
                  generic.UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'edit_profile_page.html'
    form_class = ProfileForm
    success_message = 'Updated Profile'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('show_profile_page')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        profile = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == profile.user:
            return True
        return False
```

URLS.PY

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>/profile/', ShowProfilePageView.as_view(),
         name="show_profile_page"),
    path('<int:pk>/edit_profile_page/', EditProfile.as_view(),
         name='edit_profile_page'),
]
```

FORMS.PY

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
            'bio',
            'country',
        ]
        widgets = {
            'bio': SummernoteWidget(),
            'country': CountrySelectWidget(),
        }
```

I am expecting after submitting the form to redirect to home page. The profile page uses `websiteurl/id/profile` as path to view profile. i thought that redirecting to the ShowProfilePageView after submitting the form using reverse_lazy but i cant seem to find anyway of it working and have hit a block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url pattern for `show_profile_page` needs an id as argument which you are not passing:

```
path('<int:pk>/profile/', ShowProfilePageView.as_view(),
             name="show_profile_page")
```

pass it like this:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse_lazy('show_profile_page', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

Comment: Ah Amazing thank you so much that worked. I did try something similar to that, 


`return reverse_lazy('show_profile_page', kwargs={'pk'})`

but that didn't work, I'm assuming that the self.object.pk gets the profile pk from the profile it is currently on?

But thank you so much, newer to django and python so still learning.